# Selenium issue with i frames

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Enter a consumer no and select a region, go to the next page, download the pdf. These are the steps that I am trying to automate.

I am trying to download a PDF file which seems to be embedded in an iFrame is this the right way for that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "http://www.kseb.in/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
    (By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, 'ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/')]")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@class='userInputText']"))).send_keys("11230")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.ID, "office"))).send_keys("adoor")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.NAME, "b_submit_0"))).submit()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
    (By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, 'ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/bill_view_click.php')]")))
# print(driver.current_url)

# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
#     (By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, 'ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/bill_view_click.php')]")))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.ID, "download"))).click()
```

It is not working. Know any reason why?

Comment: Can you update the question with the manual steps which you are trying to automate?

Comment: Enter a consumer no and select a region, go to the next page, download the pdf. These are the steps that I am trying to automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath to locate the `<iframe>`:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'ksebuser/orumabills/upload/billview/')]")
```

Then `switch_to` the `<iframe>`:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

---

Here's how to switch back to the default content (out of the `<iframe>`):

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)` to interfere in the iframe.

But don't forget to go back using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`.

the code below will work

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.kseb.in/index.php?
            option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=813&lang=en')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("blockrandom")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
s = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('office'))
s.select_by_value('5617')
driver.find_element_by_id('t_consumer-no_5').send_keys('11230')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/input').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```